# The connection to the OPC server drops after first connection throurg the WCF service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, subscription, opc

I have a WCF service as an OPC client that interfaces with an OPC DA server, also I have a WCF client that interacts with WCF and launches it (uses its methods)
The problem is that:
When I use WCF method `connectToOPC()` at first time, the connection can be break after few seconds, or not. `DataChange` stops coming. 
But when I restart `connectToOPC`, the connection remains active and does not fall. What happens and why?

WCF Service:

```
public void connectToOPC(string OPCUrl, int GroupUpdateTime)
{
    try
    {
        Main(OPCUrl, GroupUpdateTime);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Log(ex.Message, ""); }
}

public bool Run(string OPCUrl, int GroupUpdateTime)
    {
        try
        {
            url = new Opc.URL(OPCUrl);
            server.Connect(url, new Opc.ConnectData(new System.Net.NetworkCredential()));

            groupState = new Opc.Da.SubscriptionState();
            groupState.Name = "MyGroup";
            groupState.UpdateRate = GroupUpdateTime;
            groupState.Active = true;

            groupRead = (Opc.Da.Subscription)server.CreateSubscription(groupState);
            groupRead.DataChanged += new Opc.Da.DataChangedEventHandler(group_DataChanged);

            items = new Opc.Da.Item[ListOfTags.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < ListOfTags.Count; i++)
            {
                items[i] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[i].ItemName = ListOfTags[i];
            }
            items = groupRead.AddItems(items);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex.Message, "");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
        void group_DataChanged(object subscriptionHandle, object requestHandle,Opc.Da.ItemValueResult[] values)
    {
        //its stops here at first time  
    }
```

And code of WCF client(WPF):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    OPCClient client;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        client = new OPCClient("BasicHttpBinding_IOPC");
    }

    private void buttonOpcRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GroupUpdateTime = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxUpdateGroupTime.Text);
            client.connectToOPC(OPCUrl, GroupUpdateTime);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex + "");
        }
    }
}
```